# How do I filter a store list in sveltekit?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit

Trying to return messages that match `parentId = id`.

I'm not sure how to pass an argument to the function:

```
export const getReplies = derived([id], ([$messages, $id]) => {
    return $messages.filter(msg => {
        return msg.parentId === $id;
    });
});
```

component:

`$: replies = getReplies(msg.id);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a function that returns a derived store

```js
function getReplies(id) {
 return derived(
   messages, 
   $messages => $messages.filter(msg => msg.parentId == id)
 )
}
```

and you use it the same:

```
$: replies = getReplies(msg.id)
```

Now `replies` is a store (so you access it with $replies) and it will update everytime either messages (the original store) changes, or if `msg.id` changes (at that moment a new derived store will be generated for you.

Answer (score 1):

The [`derived`](https://svelte.dev/docs#run-time-svelte-store-derived) function returns a `store`.
If your `messages` are a `store` and the `id` is a `store`, you can
derive from both, like this:

```
const replies = derived([messages, id], ([$messages, $id]) => {
  return $messages.filter(msg => {
    return msg.parentId === $id;
  });
})
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/d3553520239a49dc8a0bc8b147b14cf2?version=3.46.4

---

Or you don't need to use `derived` at all, like:

```
$: replies = $messages.filter(msg => {
        return msg.parentId === id;
  });
```

Working example: https://svelte.dev/repl/ab500b1bd0914172b7b409e044b5fa01?version=3.46.4

Comment: the `id` is just an argument....`messages` is a store. I just want to filter it.

Comment: so you can create a store for the id, and update the store, like `$: idStore.set(id)`